# AsyncContext, timeouts, and retries

Tags: tomcat, gwt, jetty, resteasy, asynchttpclient

We have a client/server web app with a lot of components - including AsyncContext and ning AsyncHttpClient in our proxy - and I'm just trying to figure out how timeouts and retries (and startAsync/complete) work.  Here's the full structure (simplified)...

GWT 2.7 app that in response to an action (eg, button click) makes a call to a servlet on the application server, which goes through our proxy servlet to another host to execute a long running task.  In development, we run/debug the GWT app using the embedded jetty server - in production we deploy the war to tomcat7.

The first servlet uses RestEasy 3.0.8 (and ApacheHttpClient4Executor) to create the call that goes through our proxy servlet.  There we're using ning AsyncHttpClient 1.7.5, startAsync/complete, and a AsyncHandler to call the server on the remote host (which also uses RestEasy). This was setup by someone else who I'm not able to consult currently.

I'm not sure when to call complete() or how to stop/enable retries.  Two of the bigger issues are that we often get IllegalStateException's (IDLE,initial) if we complete() on/around a timeout (either within the proxy on context timeout or a call to the remote server that [AsyncResponse] timed out there); and... Jetty seems to completely restart the request (in the proxy) one time when the context timeout occurs, with no apparent way for us to check if this is happening or (intelligently) stopping it, etc. So if the call was using an input stream, the second/retry uses the same input stream which results in the remote server throwing an EOF exception (because there are no bytes left to read) on the second call, meanwhile the first call it received continues to be processed.  These are both issues with Jetty in our dev environment but I want to understand this to do the right thing on tomcat/production.

What I've tried/learned...

- the RestEasy/ApacheHttpClient4Executor call never seems to timeout (and so setting retries doesn't matter) - it either succeeds or fails, based on what happens at the other end(s) of the call (and seemingly waits forever)...  for example...

  HttpParams params = client.getParams();
  HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 5000);
  HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 5000);

  ((AbstractHttpClient) client).setHttpRequestRetryHandler(new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(3, true));
- setConnectionTimeoutInMs() on AsyncHttpClientConfig seems to do absolutely nothing (unless it's only on how long it takes to make the server connection - I thought it included the full request time)
- if I startAsync with a timeout and execute a request, if/when it times out before the request completes, then context listeners will get an onTimeout event, and Jetty will restart the entire request (leading to the listeners also getting an onStartAsync event for the same context). Tomcat doesn't do this.  Another person seems to have encountered the same thing but there were no replies...

http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-dev/msg02269.html

- calling complete() in the onTimeout stops the second request. Calling complete() instead in the onStartAsync instead gives strange results (the second call occurs still, and onComplete in the AsyncHandler gets called at some point but then it throws an IllegalStateException which results in onThrowable being called [??])
- setting retries on AsyncHttpClient in this configuration doesn't seem to do anything (unless it only happens on some combination of asyncTimeout, requestTimeout, etc - that I have yet to figure out)
- setting the response status (to 408 for example) seems to work in rare cases but often does not due to the EOF exception on the server generating a 500 that gets back to the client without me being able to do much about it (the first call is still in progress, I don't know that this is the second call [other than that it failed] or that it occurred due to a timeout, etc)
- very little information can be gathered from methods on AsyncContext. I can use reflection to get some data I can use but without that... how do I know if it's been retried? how do I know what state it is to determine whether to call complete()? etc etc
- there seems to be very little good information on AsyncContext (et al) online, confusing javadoc, and only small/isolated fix suggestions on SO. The best that I've come across so far is this:

http://www.softwareengineeringsolutions.com/blogs/2010/08/13/asynchronous-servlets-in-servlet-spec-3-0/

Bottom line: can anyone explain or point me to good documentation on how AsynContext/AsyncHandler work and/or how to use it properly and/or help me make sense of what I'm seeing here. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Sean! Did you ever solve your problem or gain a better understanding of how all of this works?

Comment: Sort of, on both counts. I still have some info to read but it's lower priority now that I'm just using one timeout (request) and got things mostly working. Still hoping for a thorough explanation from an expert, or pointer(s). Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Thanks! Any link you found you can point me to? I'm also looking for a better understanding of async servlets (I'm trying to diagnose a bug which seems to happen with jetty, related to timeouts and retries...)

Comment: If it's any consolation, controlling the status codes coming out of AsyncContext calls is still inscrutable and poorly documented eight years later.